# qsort and std::sort behaving differently

Tags: c++, sorting, qsort

I am very amazed that sorting via `qsort` and `std::sort` can produce different results. I need help explaining the behavior of the following snippets:

1. using `qsort`:

   ```
   // the following comparator has been used in qsort.
   // if l<r : -1, l==r : 0 , l>r 1
   int cmpre(const void *l, const void *r) {
       if ((*(tpl *)l).fhf < (*(tpl *)r).fhf)
           return -1;
       else
       if ((*(tpl *)l).fhf == (*(tpl *)r).fhf) {
           if ((*(tpl *)l).nhf == (*(tpl *)r).nhf)
               return 0;
           else
           if ((*(tpl *)l).nhf > (*(tpl *)r).nhf)
               return 1;
           else
               return -1;
       } else
           return 1;
   }

   // and sort statement looks like : 
   qsort(tlst, len, sizeof(tpl), cmpre);
   ```

   Complete Code link =>
   http://ideone.com/zN87tX
2. Using sort:

   ```
   // the following comparator was used for sort 
   int cmpr(const tpl &l, const tpl &r) {
       if (l.fhf < r.fhf)
           return -1;
       else
       if (l.fhf == r.fhf) {
           if (l.nhf == r.nhf)
               return 0;
           else
           if (l.nhf > r.nhf)
               return 1;
           else
               return -1;
        } else
            return 1;
   }
   // and sort statement looks like : 
   sort(tlst, tlst + len, cmpr);
   ```

   Complete code link at => 
   http://ideone.com/37Dc2S

You can see the output on the link, after and before sorting operation and may wish to check out the `compr` and `compre` methods used to compare two tuples. I do not understand why `sort` is not able to sort the array whereas `qsort` is able to do so.

Comment: The spec for comparison function of `qsort` and `sort` are _different_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite `cmpr()` as

```
bool cmpr(const tpl &l, const tpl &r){
    if(l.fhf != r.fhf) return l.fhf < r.fhf;
    return l.nhf < r.nhf;
}
```

Or, you may also reuse `cmpre()` to implement `cmpr()`.

```
bool cmpr(const tpl &l, const tpl &r) {
    return (cmpre(&l, &r) < 0);
}
```

Comment: Why are the compare functions for sort and qsort are different. Thanks for the quick answer . :-) What I mean is that why C++ expects different nature of compare function for sort and qsort. What could have been in the mind of the designers that they did this.

Comment: @prem `qsort` comes from C.  They are very different code bases written by and for different people.  In C++, `sort` expects something similar to `<`, which returns a `bool`.  In C, there is no such constraint.